# Issue with merge sort

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I'm trying to run merge sort using python and recursion it is working fine for some cases not not working fine for most of the cases please correct me I tried and unable to find error in code.

```
def merge_sort(a, min, max):
    if max - min < 2:
        return a[min:max]

    mid = (min + max) // 2
    L = merge_sort(a, min, mid)
    R = merge_sort(a, mid, max)
    return (sort(L, R))

def sort(L, R):
    (c, m, n) = ([], len(L), len(R))
    (i, j) = (0, 0)
    while (i + j < m + n):
        if i == m:
            c.append(R[j])
            j += 1
        elif j == m:
            c.append(L[i])
            i += 1
        elif R[j] <= L[i]:
            c.append(R[j])
            j += 1
        elif L[i] < R[j]:
            c.append(L[i])
            i += 1
    return c
```

Comment: Hi, is this for some sort of assignment? I ask, because sort algorithm are already implemented in many librarys [like numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo there, it should be `j==n` in the second case.

Next one is not an error, but it is usual to prefer the equal element coming from the *left* argument over the one on the right, for the sort to be *stable* (not change the order of elements unnecessarily). So you also need to switch the `<=` and the `<` comparisons in the other two cases.

*Naming* is also important. The `sort` function is really *`sorted_merge`*.